# keyboard shortcut to rename the title of terminal?

Tags: terminal, keyboard, shortcut

I have switched from Ubuntu to macOS (**Sierra 10.12.5**) recently and I am missing few very basic keyboard shortcut in the terminal.

I used to open multiple terminal in tabs and set name of each tab  but couldn't find any keyboard shortcut so far, although I am using <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd> which open the inspector window separately and there I can set the title name but again there is no way to close that inspector window using keyboard.

Kindly tell us if there any shortcut to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are *almost there*.

You can open the inspector to set the title name with <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>

In order to close it you can press <kbd>ESC</kbd>
 OR use the inspector toggle shortcut - <kbd>CMD</kbd> + <kbd>I</kbd>